# Ошибка при создании композиции

Tags: c#, ооп

Я не силен в ООП. Помогите мне правильно спроектировать классы.

**SchoolReport.cs**

```
public class SchoolReport
{
    public string SchoolName { get; set; }
    public string AreaName { get; set; }

    public List<LearnerReport> LearnerReports { get; set; }        
}
```

**LearnerReport.cs**

```
public class LearnerReport //Лист оценки обучающегося
{
    //данные обучающегося        
    public string SNS { get; set; } //ФИО участника        
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
}
```

**LearnerReport_201636.cs**

```
//2016-36 - Готовность 1 классов 2016/2017
public class LearnerReport_201636 : LearnerReport
{
    public double? PrimaryMark { get; set; }
    public string OldGroupName { get; set; } //Возрастная группа: 6-7 лет/7-8 лет        
    public string WasOrWasntDOO_str { get; set; } //ДА/НЕТ
    public string WasOrWasnt_str { get; set; }    //ДА/НЕТ
    public string TestResult5Name { get; set; } //Какая группа на основе тестового балла
    public string ValueArray { get; set; } //Баллы за задания = 1;1;0;0;1...
}
```

**SchoolReport_201636.cs**

```
public class SchoolReport_201636 : SchoolReport
{

}
```

Как вы видите в SchoolReport присутствует `композиция`. Как мне теперь правильно в конкретной реализации `SchoolReport_201636` указать конкретную реализацию `LearnerReports_201636`?

Я пытаюсь это сделать так:

**Program.cs**

```
SchoolReport schoolReport = new SchoolReport_201636();
schoolReport.LearnerReports = new List<LearnerReport_201636>(); //ТУТ ОШИБКА
```

но на второй строке кода среда показывает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я не так делаю?

Comment: какие действия планируются с полем: `public List<LearnerReport> LearnerReports`?

Comment: @Grundy туда будут добавлять объекты `LearnerReport`, которые будут формироваться из строк БД.

Comment: любые LearnerReport или только `LearnerReport_201636`?

Comment: @Grundy любые. Если я правильно понял принципы `SOLID`, то наверное любые.

Comment: То есть для `SchoolReport_201636` могут быть добавлены `LearnerReport` из других школ?

Comment: @Grundy нет. В данном случае речь идет о создании отчета для `одной` школы.

Comment: Тогда, да, ответ @andreycha подходит

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можете использовать обобщения:

```
public class SchoolReport<T> where T : LearnerReport
{
    public string SchoolName { get; set; }
    public string AreaName { get; set; }

    public List<T> LearnerReports { get; set; }        
}

public class SchoolReport_201636 : SchoolReport<LearnerReport_201636>
{
}
```

Теперь компилируется:

```
var schoolReport = new SchoolReport_201636();
schoolReport.LearnerReports = new List<LearnerReport_201636>();
```

---

Также можно воспользоваться [ковариантностью](http://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/charp_theory/level11/11_14.php) и объявить список `LearnerReports` как `IEnumerable<LearnerReport>` (спасибо @Grundy за подсказку). Но применение этого способа зависит от ваших требований:

```
public class SchoolReport
{
    public string SchoolName { get; set; }
    public string AreaName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<LearnerReport> LearnerReports { get; set; }        
}
```

Comment: разве пример автора является *[Композицией](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))*? вроде же *[наследование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))*

Comment: @Bald таки почему вы это у меня спрашиваете? :) Но попробую ответить: композицией тут является связь школа-ученик. Именно с ней (вместе с наследованием) у автора возникла проблемы.

Comment: а если на IEnumerable<LearnerReport>  заменить List<LearnerReport>, будет присваиваться?

Comment: я спрашиваю у Вас так как я сам не до конца уверен, а вашем ответе нет уточнения что это не композиция а наследования. поэтому и уточняю у Вас

Comment: @Bald. хоть горшком обзови

Comment: действительно будет :)

Comment: @Bald я ответил непосредственно на вопрос автора. А исправлять все остальные огрехи в коде и терминологии у меня не всегда есть настроение :).

Comment: @andreycha спасибо за пояснение. да действительно композиция в приведенном примере автором имеет место быть(проглядел после того как увидел явное наследование).

Comment: @Grundy кстати да, еще один трюк, спасибо :). Добавил в ответ.

Comment: @andreycha, он тут не особо подходит :-) потому что как я понял автор будет менять этот список, а с IEnumerable - Это не просто :-)

Comment: @Grundy да, зависит от сценариев использования. Но для полноты картины подойдет.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы будете использовать список элементов типа базового класса

```
SchoolReport schoolReport = new SchoolReport_201636();
schoolReport.LearnerReports = new List<LearnerReport>();
```

,то вы сможете использовать его для добавления объектов класса-наследника

```
var lr_201636 = new LearnerReport_201636 
{
   PrimaryMark = 4.0,
   OldGroupName = "7-8 лет ",
   WasOrWasntDOO_str = "ДА",
   WasOrWasnt_str = "ДА",
   TestResult5Name ="Хорошист"
};
schoolReport.LearnerReports.Add(lr_201636);
```

Но при взятии элемента из списка, его придётся приводить к типу, если вам надо явно пользоваться свойствами наследника.

```
double mark =  (LearnerReport_201636)schoolReport.LearnerReports[0];
```

И это плохо, так как если в списке окажется экземпляр другого класса, то выбросится исключение. Но если для элементов списка не требуется использовать методы и свойства классов-наследников, например вы определили какой-нибудь метод в предке, а в наследнике его перегрузили

```
public class LearnerReport //Лист оценки обучающегося
{
    //данные обучающегося        
    public string SNS { get; set; } //ФИО участника        
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public virtual string GetFullInfo()
    {
        return string.Format
           ("ФИО:{0}; Класс{1}",
           SNS, ClassName);
    }
}

//2016-36 - Готовность 1 классов 2016/2017
public class LearnerReport_201636 : LearnerReport
{
    public double? PrimaryMark { get; set; }
    public string OldGroupName { get; set; } //Возрастная группа: 6-7 лет/7-8 лет        
    public string WasOrWasntDOO_str { get; set; } //ДА/НЕТ
    public string WasOrWasnt_str { get; set; }    //ДА/НЕТ
    public string TestResult5Name { get; set; } //Какая группа на основе тестового балла
    public string ValueArray { get; set; } //Баллы за задания = 1;1;0;0;1...

    public override string GetFullInfo()
    {
        return base.GetFullInfo +
           string.Format
           ("; Оценка:{0}; Возраст {1}",
           PrimaryMark, OldGroupName);
    }
}
```

, то можно выполнить что-нибудь подобное

```
foreach(var lr in schoolReport.LearnerReports)
{   
    Console.WriteLine(lr.GetFullInfo());
}
```